# How to create sha1 checksums of files inside a tar archive without using much disk space

Tags: command-line, pipe, tar, hashsum

I would like to get the sha1 checksums of all files inside a simple tar archive as a list, or a new file

Without using the disk space to unpack the big tar file. Something with piping and calculating the sha1 on the fly, directing the output to /dev/null

I searched google a lot and did some experiments with pipes but could not get very far.

Would really save me a lot of time checking backups.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Too easy :

```
tar xvJf myArchive.tar.xz --to-command=sha1sum
```

The result is like this :

```
z/
z/DOCUMENTATION
3c4d9df9bcbd1fb756b1aaba8dd6a2db788a8659 *-
z/getnameenv.sh
1b7f1ef4bbb229e4dc5d280c3c9835d9d061726a *-
```

Or create "tarsha1.sh" with :

```
#!/bin/bash

sha1=`sha1sum`
echo -n $sha1 | sed 's/ .*$//'
echo " $TAR_FILENAME"
```

Then use it this way :

```
tar xJf myArchive.tar.xz --to-command=./tarsha1.sh
```

The result is like this :

```
3c4d9df9bcbd1fb756b1aaba8dd6a2db788a8659 z/DOCUMENTATION
1b7f1ef4bbb229e4dc5d280c3c9835d9d061726a z/getnameenv.sh
```

Comment: awesome. yes it is easy when you know the trtick ;) will try it out

Comment: I realized that I have a crippled tar on a busybox machine, so maybe you can also help on my followup question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303701

Comment: For mac users: you have to use GNU tar instead of the system default BSD tar for the `--to-command` option.

Answer (score 0):

This is an incremental improvement on Vouze's answer to make the output of the script look exactly like the normal output of GNU's `*sum`.

The following version of `tarhash.sh` handles the situation where the filename contains a newline or backslash in the same way that the current version of `md5sum`/`sha1sum`/... does, in case that turns out to be necessary. It also preserves the two spaces between the sum and the filename (or the single space and `*`, if you change the command from `sha1sum` to `sha1sum --binary`).

As long as the filenames are sorted in the same way (or if you sort both sides first), the output of this script can be compared to an original `sha1sum` output using your favorite diff tool.

`tarhash.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
(echo -n "`sha1sum`" | sed 's/-$//' && echo -n "$TAR_FILENAME") |
sed -z 's/\\/\\\\/g; s/\n/\\n/g; /\\/ s/^/\\/; s/$/\n/;'
```

Usage:

```bsh
# Note: In this tar invocation, make sure not to specify -v
# (The output comes out wrong if it is included).
tar xJf myArchive.tar.xz --to-command=./tarhash.sh > sha1sums.txt
```